# Chaining commands together in .bashrc

Tags: bash

I'm trying to chain two commands together in a function or alias.
What I want to do is ssh into a proxy box, and then into another box from there. So something like:

```
ssh -J mylogin@host mylogin@host2
```

So far i've tried:

```
function doot {ssh -J mylogin@host && mylogin@"$1"}
```

and:

```
function doot {ssh -J mylogin@host; mylogin@"$1"}
```

and:

```
alias doot="ssh -J mylogin@host; mylogin@"$1""
```

It either doesn't recognize the function, or the alias just gives me an error. I feel that it's having an issue with the "$1" but i'm not sure how to chain these two commands together.

I want to just type in doot [nameofhost] and execute the command

```
ssh -J mylogin@host mylogin@host2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your attempted functions or alias do `ssh -J mylogin@host mylogin@host2`. Why?

The use of `&&` and `';'` separate *commands*. In your case that would make two separate commands out of `ssh -J mylogin@host` and `mylogin@"$1"`. You need a single command specifying `mylogin@host` as the jump-host and `mylogin@"$1"` as the final destination. Simply do:

```bash
doot() { 
  ssh -J mylogin@host mylogin@"$1"
}
```

(**note:** quotes are not wrong but not entirely needed as hostnames don't contain whitespace. Also note `"$1"` within the *function* refers to the function argument, not the command line argument for your script. You would need to call as `doot "$1"`. There is no `';'` or `&&` involved.)

There is a problem with `alias` as an alias does not contain arguments. From man bash:

```
There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.
If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see FUNCTIONS below).
```

Also, you want to validate that `$1` has been given. You can do that with:

```bash
[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate at least one argument given
  printf "error: destination hostname required as argument.\n" >&2
  return 1
}
```

(**note:** if you are calling the function that includes this test from the command line in the parent shell, your function should `return` instead of `exit`. In that case `exit` would exit the parent shell. If you use the function within a separate script you call from the parent, then you want `exit` to close the subshell)

Comment: You can't use `$1` in an alias definition to refer to the "argument" to the alias. And I don't believe there is any mechanism to concatenate the first word following the alias expansion to the last word in the alias expansion. Better to go with the advice from `man bash`: "There  is  no  mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used."

Comment: Good catch! Thank you, (must have been sleeping, I knew that...)

Comment: David's response actually worked perfectly for what I was doing. Thank you all so much!

Comment: It's unlikely you want a function to call `exit`; the *caller* of the function should decide if exiting the script is warranted. You can just use `ssh -J mylogin@host mylogin@"${1:-error: destination required}"`; the parameter expansion itself will cause the function to return early with an exit status of 1 if no argument is provided.

Comment: @chepner - correct, that should be `return`. (depends on where it is called -- command line, then `return`, or if incorporated in another script and run in a subshell, then `exit`)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if the proxy required any additional parameters, sssuming it just a jump box, allowing ssh

```
Function foo { 
    ssh mylogin@host ssh mylogin@host2
}
```

If your current user is ‘mylogin’, you can abbreviate to

```
ssh host ssh host2
```